# Is $T:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]: Tf(x)=\frac12 x f(x^2)+1$ a contraction?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, functional-equations

I am a non-mathematician (a  physicist) who wants to find a continuous function on $[0,1]$ that satisfies the relation $f(x)=\frac12 x f(x^2)+1$ with $0\le x\le 1$. I need it for one of my models.

This is what I've got sofar.

I want to use [Banach's contraction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem#Statement).

Define $T:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]: (Tf)(x)=\frac12 x f(x^2)+1$. If $T$ is a contraction, the Banach's contraction theorem yields that $Tf=f$ and that solves my problem. I know that C[0,1] is a complete normed space with regard to $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{\infty}$

I do not know how to show that $T$ is a contraction. Can someone show me how do do this?

Answer (score 1):

Define $\|f\|_\infty := \max_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x)|$, for all $f\in C[0,1]$. Given $f, g\in C[0,1]$ and $x\in [0,1]$,

$$|Tf(x) - Tg(x)| = \left|\left(\frac{1}{2}xf(x^2) + 1\right) -\left(\frac{1}{2}xg(x^2) + 1\right)\right| = \frac{|x|}{2}|f(x^2) - g(x^2)| \le \frac{1}{2}\|f - g\|_\infty.$$

Thus $$\|Tf - Tg\|_\infty \le \frac{1}{2}\|f - g\|.$$ So $T$ is a contraction (with contraction constant $\frac{1}{2}$).

Answer (score 0):

Now that @kobe has demonstrated that the operator is a contraction, this justifies the search for the unique fixed point of this operator. This can be achieved by assuming that $f$ can be represented by a power series $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$. It is clear that $f(0)=1$, so $a_0=1$. Now if you plug in this series into your equation, and then compare coefficients, you will arrive at the unique fixed point: $$f(x) = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2^n-1}}{2^n}.$$ You can verify that this works by plugging it into $$f(x) = \frac12 x f(x^2) + 1.$$

Comment: If you require more details, I can provide them. On the other hand, once you have a candidate, all you need to do is test it. By uniqueness it must be the solution you are looking for.

Comment: A cute way to arrive at this power series is to use the method in the proof of the Banach fixed point thereom. Take any function and iterate the operator on it. In particular, take the function $g(x) = 1$ and iteratively apply the operation to it. This will spin out a term in the series one at a time.